# Spurious URL structure (Adding extra /0/s)

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

We have just used a reputable external crawler to test our site and it is listing many (1,000s) of pages that have /0/ or /0/0/ or /0/0/0/ etc appended to the URL
so https://example.com/news/news-post-title/0/0/0/0/ and, it claims, you can trace the  inbound link back one 0 and / at at a time to https://example.com/news/news-post-title/0 and then that page without the /0 ie https://example.com/news/news-post-title.

All these posts 'exist', no 404, in that they are clones of the original post (not just posts, category archives also). in contrast https://example.com/news/news-post-title/1/ returns, correctly, a 404 error.

I have flushed the rewrite rules to no effect. I can see no link in the code.

The plugins we have that are suspect are Yoast and Polylang together with Wordpress' native rewrite.

So two questions; 1. where are they coming from if they are not in the source code and 2, how do I get rid?

Comment: Further research implies this could be due to a returning AJAX call. I have two AJAX functions on the site and the both end with `wp_die()`

Comment: Do these sites have the `canonical` URL set correctly? If so, it is not an issue usually

Comment: are you sure they're independent separate posts and not the same post with the same canonical URL? It sounds like you have a hyperlink with `href="0"` or something similar in your code and it's blindly following it. You can disable yoast and polylang to test your theory those are suspect. Otherwise what is the problem you're concerned this will cause?

Comment: They are the same post. my impression is the crawler is following an Ajax 'load more' which is returning the extra '/0' The problem is that we used a crawler to test the site and it gave up after 20,000 pages. Disabling Yoast and Polylang and flushing the rules did nothing. But I have used this AJAX method before without causing the issue (if, as you say it's an issue)